Click the button and move Fragment/Activity (Kotlin)
After creating Bottom Navigation in Activity, we are writing the main code by creating Fragment.
The question here is, when you click a button within Fragment, do you think it's better to go to Activity? Do you think it's better to go to Fragment?
The problem is that the bottom navigation is visible because it is a movement between fragments within the same activity.
After clicking the button, I don't want to see Bottom Navigation on the screen to move.
If I make it with Fragment, I have to set up visibility so that bottom navigation is not visible, but I am wondering if I should put this code in it.
Or if there is any other way, please let me know.
For your information, the screen that you want to move is the screen that you write in Edit Text, save, and save to the Firebase Realtime Database, Storage.
If you have any additional questions, please ask me.
Thank you for reading it.
Click the button to declare the screen to move as Fragment, but the problem is that Bottom Navigation comes out.
Is it correct to use binding.bottomNavi.visibility = View.GONE within the Fragment code?
I want to write a clean code.

Use NavController for move one fragment to another Activity. See docs.

Oh, the Fragment movement is done with the NavController.
If you click the button, you will see a screen to save your writing.
Is it better to make the screen to save this article Fragment or Activity.
If you make it into Fragment, it's a problem because you see Bottom Navigation. :(
Thank you for reading :)
